# ROR - heroku strange behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've jest spent a few hours resolving a problem with heroku. It occurred in the following line:

```
if @user.encrypt_password (params[:user][:old_password]) == @user.encrypted_password || (current_user.can?(:edit_user)  && @user.status != 0)
```

And it worked after a really slight modification:

```
if @user.encrypt_password(params[:user][:old_password]) == @user.encrypted_password || (current_user.can?(:edit_user)  && @user.status != 0)
```

After 'if @user.encrypt_password' at first I put a 'space' by accident. On my local machine it worked fine, but on heroku it resulted in a nasty error:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>
> We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it
>   shortly.

I checked everything twice, this definitely is the problem. What was that? Different versions of ruby? I really have no idea... If I can't get any info from heroku, than it would be nice to at least have the same errors on my local machine so I could read them...

Does anybody have any ideas?

Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but it was probably a parser error. With the space there, it ended up taking everything that followed as the argument, I imagine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right, but that's not the case. The thing is why it worked on the local machine without errors and than caused a crash on heroku. And finally how to make a local machine behave like heroku to prevent such unexpected errors from happening.